# Determine Publishing Page check-in/publish status programmatically

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, check-out

Is there a way to determine the check-in/publish status of a Publishing Page programmatically?

For example to determine

- whether the page is checked out (and to whom),
- whether the page has a published version,

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [Level property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.level.aspx) of the SPFile object. It's a [SPFileLevel  enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilelevel.aspx) with these possible values:Published, Draft, Checkout